# Compile-time concatenation of std::initializer_list's

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, initializer-list

I would like to write some code like the following:

```
using int_list_t = std::initializer_list<int>;

struct ThreeDimensionalBox {
  static constexpr int_list_t kDims = {1, 2, 3};
};

struct FourDimensionalBox {
  static constexpr int_list_t kDims = {4, 5, 6, 7};
};

template<typename Box1, typename Box2>
struct CombinedBox {
  static constexpr int_list_t kDims = Box1::kDims + Box2::kDims;  // error
};

using SevenDimensionalBox = CombinedBox<ThreeDimensionalBox, FourDimensionalBox>;
```

Is there some way to fix the implementation of `CombinedBox`, so that `SevenDimensionalBox::kDims` is effectively bound to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`?

I know that I can replace `std::initializer_list<int>` with a custom template class with a variadic int template parameter list, with concatenation effectively achieved via standard metaprogramming recursion techniques. I was just wondering if a solution exists using only `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Why are you using `std::initializer_list` here? That is not what it is meant for and you will easily cause dangling references with this. You probably should be using `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` can be initialized only as empty, with a list of brace-enclosed elements, or by copy.

However even with a copy construction, the lifetime of the actual array that `std::initializer_list` references is determined by the lifetime of the original `std::initializer_list` object that was initialized by a brace-enclosed element list. In other words copying the `std::initializer_list` does not copy the array or extend its lifetime.

Therefore it is impossible to concatenate `std::initializer_list`s. They are not meant to be used as a container. A `std::initializer_list` should mostly be used only as a function parameter as a lightweight way to pass a brace-enclosed list of elements of unspecified size to a function for it to then process the elements further.

You probably want `std::array` instead. Something like this (requiring C++17, but not C++20):

```
struct ThreeDimensionalBox {
  static constexpr auto kDims = std::array{1, 2, 3};
};

struct FourDimensionalBox {
  static constexpr auto kDims = std::array{4, 5, 6, 7};
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
constexpr auto concat_arrays(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<T, M>& b) {
    // assumes `T` is default-constructible
    std::array<T, N+M> r;
    std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(r));
    std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::begin(r)+N);
    return r;
}

template<typename Box1, typename Box2>
struct CombinedBox {
  static constexpr auto kDims = concat_arrays(Box1::kDims, Box2::kDims);
};

using SevenDimensionalBox = CombinedBox<ThreeDimensionalBox, FourDimensionalBox>;
```

Comment: *In other words copying does not copy the array or extend its lifetime.* Only sometimes.  *except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary* source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: @NathanOliver Should be better now.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks. My motivation for trying to do something like this stemmed from my ignorance about how `std::array` could be used at compile time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`std::initializer_list` has exactly and only one purpose: to be a tool for initializing an object, within the scope where a braced-init-list (the stuff in `{}`) was used for the initialization of that object. Everything about this type is built for that purpose, and it has a bunch of firewalls in place to prevent you from doing basically anything else with it.

The most important of which is that `initializer_list` doesn't actually store anything; it *references* an array of values which is stored elsewhere (namely, the cite of the `{}` that created it). Since it does not store the array, and they're only meant to be build from the `{}` grammatical construct, you cannot give them an array to reference. They can only get an array from an existing `initializer_list` object via copying, and that one could only get one either from a `{}` or an existing `initializer_list` which could only get one from... well, you get the idea.

If you need to do compile-time array manipulation, `std::array` is a better tool. If you want to concatenate two braced-init-lists and use the result to initialize some object... you can't do that.

Do not try to use `initializer_list` as a quick-and-dirty array type. Only use it for initializing objects.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. My motivation for trying to do something like this stemmed from my ignorance about how `std::array` could be used at compile time. Thanks!